# $F(x) = \int_a^b \frac{x^2}{1+2\sin^3(t) + \sin^6(t) } dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $F(x) = \int_a^b \frac{x^2}{1+2\sin^3(t) + \sin^6(t) } dt$ i have to calculate the derivative of $F(x)$ with respect to $x$.

Let $g(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+2\sin^3(x) + \sin^6(x)}$ then $g$ is continuos for all $x \in R$, so $F´(x) = g(b) - g(a) = \frac{b^2}{1+2\sin^3(b) + \sin^6(b)} - \frac{a^2}{1+2\sin^3(a) + \sin^6(a)} $ is that correct?

Comment: Well... factor out the $x^2$ and get that "ugly" coefficient. Derivate and get $2x\cdot (\text{"ugly" coefficient thing})$. If you want $t^2$ in the numerator instead of $x^2$, then $F$ is independent of $x$ (as a function of $a$ and $b$), whence $F'(x) = 0$.

Comment: As for your answer, it is a "common" mistake after learning FTC. Why do you think it does not apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$F(x) = \int_a^b \frac{x^2}{1+2\sin^3(t) + \sin^6(t) } dt=:x^2 f(a,b)$$ 
where

$$f(a,b) = \int_a^b \frac{1}{1+2\sin^3(t) + \sin^6(t) } dt$$

So

$$F'(x)=2x f(a,b)$$